# how can i make a react component to update after first api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, lifecycle

when I call the API for the first time it will render the react component correctly with the information from the response, if I try to call the API again to get a new response, I get the new body response but the react component remains the same it doesn't update.

when I console log the new response data, the console does display the new information but I haven't been able to make the componenet rerender it.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchCv} from '../Actions';//--->fucntion will axios post
import Example from '../Components/ReactToPrint'//--->should render responses
import { SpinnerInfinity } from 'spinners-react';
import { FaArrowCircleDown } from 'react-icons/fa';








class DataList extends React.Component {

  CodeStatus = this.props.posts.status;

  state = {
    // Initially, no file is selected
    selectedFile: null,
    cargar: true,
    loader: false,
    check: false,
  };

  onFileChange = (event) => {
    // Update the file state
 this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });

    // show emailIcon

    if (this.state.cargar === true) {
      this.setState({ cargar: false });
      this.setState({ loader: true });
      this.setState({ check: false });
    } else if (this.CodeStatus === 200) {
      this.setState({ cargar: false });
      this.setState({ loader: false });
      this.setState({ check: false });
    }
  };


//posts file to api adn get response
  onFileUpload = async (fetched) => {
    await fetched;
    // Create an object of formData
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Update the formData object
    formData.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);

    // Details of the uploaded file

    this.props.fetchCv(formData).then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.setState({check:true});
        this.setState({laoder:false});
        
        return result;
      }else{
        this.setState({cargar:true});
        this.setState({loader:false});
        this.setState({check:false});
       }
    });
  };


  twoCalls = (e) => {
    // On file select (from the pop up)
    this.onFileChange(e);

    // On file upload (click the upload button)
    this.onFileUpload();

  };


  render() {
  console.log(this.props.posts)//-->logs new body response everytime api is called
    return (
      <Container>
        
        <Done>
          {this.CodeStatus == 200 ? <span>Analisis Completo <FaArrowCircleDown style={{Animation:"animationDown 3s infinite"}}/></span>: <span>Salvando otras galaxias</span> }
        </Done>
        {this.state.cargar === true ? (
          <Uploader>
              <label htmlFor={"upload-button"}>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <div className="button">Cargar Cv</div>
            </label>
            <input
              id="upload-button"
              style={{ display: "none" }}
              accept="application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
              type="file"
              onChange={this.twoCalls}
            />
          </Uploader>
        ) : null}
        <Loader>
          {this.state.cargar === false ?  <SpinnerInfinity size={100}/> :  null}
        </Loader>
        {this.state.isVisible ? <Example /> : null}//-->component that wont update with response
        {this.CodeStatus == 200 ? <Fly>
        <img className="fly" src="/images/ufo.png" alt="ufo"/>
        <img className="fly2" src="/images/apolo.png" alt="rocket"/>
        <img className="p1" src="/images/PlanetsList/1.png" alt="planet"/>
        <img className="p2" src="/images/PlanetsList/2.png" alt="planet"/>
        <img className="p3" src="/images/PlanetsList/3.png" alt="planet"/>
        <img className="p4" src="/images/PlanetsList/4.png" alt="planet"/>
        <img className="p5" src="/images/PlanetsList/5.png" alt="planet"/>
        <img className="p6" src="/images/PlanetsList/6.png" alt="planet"/>
        </Fly>:null}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}


// our state object will have a prop called data, that contains all of the data return from the reducer

function mapStateToProps(state) {

  return {
    posts: state.posts
  };

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchCv})(DataList);
```

Comment: You aren't passing these props to <Example /> at all?

Comment: yes, I'm passing the props to the component, but that happens in the file where EXAMPLE  is imported from @ChrisG

Comment: How is React supposed to realize that the props have changed unless you pass them to the component like `<Example posts={this.props.posts} />` or similar? The base mechanism of React, it's entire conceptual framework, and the reason for its name, is to re-render if (and only if) props or state changes. You're using redux, which means the alternative is to dispatch the change to the redux store and subscribe to the relevant part inside <Example />. But there has to be *some* way for React to detect that <Example /> is supposed to re-render. *If* you're doing that, you need to show relevant code

Comment: What's the structure of your `Example` component? Do you have a `useSelector`?